# In Angualr why OpenApi Generated ApiModule doesn’t register when declared in node_modules but works outside that folder?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, node-modules, openapi-generator

I’m having an issue. I need to consume OpenApi Generated files (services, interfaces) via NPM package. The problem it doesn’t work when it’s in node_modules, but if I move it outside this folder it works. ApiModule comes as undefined when in node_modules for some reason. Github link in the bottom is documentation how to use it.

The project builds, it detects the files in path but on launching website I get error:

```
app.module.ts:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forRoot')
    at Module.6747 (app.module.ts:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module.4431 (environment.ts:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at __webpack_exec__ (log$:23)
    at log$:23
    at Function.__webpack_require__.O (chunk loaded:23)
    at log$:23
    at webpackJsonpCallback (jsonp chunk loading:33)
    at main.js:1
```

AppModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

////// added
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {
  ApiModule,
  Configuration,
  ConfigurationParameters,
} from 'client-petstore';


export function apiConfigFactory(): Configuration {
  const params: ConfigurationParameters = {
    basePath: 'https://localhost:4200',
  };
  return new Configuration(params);
}
////// end

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ////// added
    ApiModule.forRoot(apiConfigFactory),
    HttpClientModule
    ////// end
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have tried this on 2 different machines running Angular 12 (Node.js v12 and v16) with:

- my locally generated file;
- “npm typescript-codegen-petstore” downloaded (requires adding
  override keyword and adding  in places it fails);
- https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/typescript-angular-v12-provided-in-root/builds/with-npm (https://download-directory.github.io to download this section)

If I put in a different folder than node_modules it works, inside it doesn’t. Any help or ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `import { ApiModule } from '@openapitools/typescript-angular-petstore';`

Comment: I downloaded the linked in OP git repository. Inside ran "npm install" and "npm run build" (just in case but nothing generated in npm package gets taken anyway).

@hawks I packed it "npm pack" to make "openapitools-typescript-angular-petstore-1.0.0.tgz"

Then in my project ran "npm i openapitools-typescript-angular-petstore-1.0.0.tgz". It detects the files as it did previously but error is the same with your path.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when publishing the module only with `npm publish` instead of `npm publish dist/`. You have to specify the folder generated by the build when publishing the packages!

I replicated the error with a test package - [maddob-petstore-test-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/maddob-petstore-test-client).

1. Version 1.0.0 is published without specifying the folder and is not working
2. Version 1.0.2 is published with specifying the dist folder and is working as expected